# Adding extra jars breaks DAO layer

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I am developing a maven project in eclpise. First I made a DAO layer then verified it - which works fine. But when I add jars to my project (for an other layer(bussiness)) the DAO layer doesn't work as intended.

The error occurs when I add this jar: `[func_frwmwk_clt,func_frwmwk_cmn,func_frwmwk_srv, func_util, ott_utilities, soi, toplink   ]` But if I remove this, the project works and gives a true result.  How can I fix this?

---

**Main class:**

```
package com.services;
import com.entity.Ws_security;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


 import com.services.Interface_ws_security_services;

public class App {




@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) {


ApplicationContext ctx1 = new  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring_hibernate.xml");
                                                                        Interface_ws_security_services service=(Interface_ws_security_services)ctx1.getBean("a");

    //Ws_security ess=new Ws_security();

    System.out.println("Done");
    Ws_security ess =service.findByidws("ess1");
    System.out.println(ess.getLogin());
    System.out.println(ess.getPassword());
    System.out.println(ess.getIPmax());
    System.out.println(ess.getIPmin());
    System.out.println("Done");


}

   }
```

---

**Error log:**

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for     logger(org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
 Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:   Error creating bean with name 'disableServiceBoxPageController' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/sayed/Desktop/DocumentationR3_33276/Client/lib/func_frwmwk_clt.jar!/com/lhs/ccb/cfw/sgu/solutionunits/servicebox/DisableServiceBoxPageController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.lhs.ccb.cfw.sgu.solutionunits.servicebox.DisableServiceBoxPageController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.lhs.ccb.func.ect.DefaultDictionary cannot be cast to com.lhs.ccb.cfw.wcs.errorhandling.CFWErrorDictionary
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1007)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.services.App.main(App.java:19)
  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not   instantiate bean class [com.lhs.ccb.cfw.sgu.solutionunits.servicebox.DisableServiceBoxPageController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.lhs.ccb.func.ect.DefaultDictionary cannot be cast to com.lhs.ccb.cfw.wcs.errorhandling.CFWErrorDictionary
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1000)
... 13 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.lhs.ccb.func.ect.DefaultDictionary   cannot be cast to com.lhs.ccb.cfw.wcs.errorhandling.CFWErrorDictionary
at com.lhs.ccb.cfw.wcs.solutionunit.AbstractPageController.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.lhs.ccb.cfwutil.ExtendedAbstractPageController.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.lhs.ccb.cfw.sgu.solutionunits.servicebox.DisableServiceBoxPageController.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
... 15 more
```

### but i not understand why this jars are called and the class main is didn't any jar from this list to work

Comment: you need to make the title more relevant.

Comment: i think this title is more attractive

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in `DisableServiceBoxPageController`'s constructor. You're trying to cast a `DefaultDictionary` into a `CFWErrorDictionary` and that doesn't seem possible.

Search the offending line and cast the object to the proper type, if possible.

---

**Edit**

If the issue is related to adding the JAR per se, it could be that a class is conflicting. Make sure you're not using multiple versions of the same JAR.

Comment: DisableServiceBoxPageController is a class from one of jars and it works for an other person

Comment: @MonsierJab Define _works for another person_. Do you have the same code? Do you have the same version? Do you reference the same jar? Did you update your repository? Did he/she update his/hers? Are you using multiple versions of the same jar?.

Comment: i not found dependency to this jars in maven central repository so i added this jars from"add external jar" in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Try placing those files that you need for business layer into a separate directory.

Comment: i not understand y can you explain more please